# Database's backup location that created by Azure Data Studio on Mac M1

Tags: sql-server, docker, macos, azure-data-studio

I have a MsSQL database in my Azure Data Studio with Docker. I tried to create a Backup file of this database, but Azure Dara Studio showed me 'Backup Files /var/opt/mssql/data/idatabase-202396-16-47-4.bak' in the backup options. How can I access this file? I want to copy this backup file to another computer.

Comment: The file paths in backup and restore operations are relative to the location of the SQL Server instance itself (not the client), so the backup will be located wherever the SQL Server instance is. When that's a Docker container then the backup is inside the container's file system, so you can use [`docker cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) to copy it out. You could save yourself some steps with future containers by using _volumes_ to mount a portion of the Docker host's file system inside the Docker container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While thinking @AlwaysLearnin 's comment, I have found that, you can access files inside the server with Docker Desktop. I put picture that where I found the .bak file.

[image]